# Finding the span of a subspace if I have its image as a matrix

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

This is at extract from a written solution to a problem:

> $$
> U_1 =  \operatorname{Im} \begin{bmatrix}
> 2\cos^2 (\theta/2) & 2\sin(\theta/2)\cos(\theta/2)\\
> 2\sin(\theta/2)cos(\theta/2) & 2\sin^2 (\theta/2)
>  \end{bmatrix}  \Rightarrow
> $$
>
> the columns are linear dependent and $ U_1 = \operatorname{span}\left( \begin{bmatrix} \cos(\theta/2) \\ \sin(\theta/2)\end{bmatrix}\right) $

I can see that the a vector that is the base of the span is a multiplier of that image. But why was it concluded that this is the span?

Comment: What do you know about the dimension of your codomain?

Comment: that $dim(R^2) = 2 ?$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image of a matrix is the span of its columns. For example, if 2-by-2 matrix $A$ has columns $\overrightarrow{a}_1$ and $\overrightarrow{a}_2$, then

$$
[\overrightarrow{a}_1 \overrightarrow{a}_2]\left[\begin{array}{c}x\\y\end{array}\right] = x \overrightarrow{a}_1 + y \overrightarrow{a}_2
$$

Since the image is the set of all outputs, $x$ and $y$ run through $\mathbb{R}$, so you get the span of the columns. A **basis** for the image is given by a maximal linearly independent set of columns.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that for a linear transformation $T:V\to W$, if $B_V=\{v_1,v_2,...,v_n\}$ is a basis of $V$, then $\text{Im}(T)$ is spanned by $\{T(v_1),T(v_2),...,T(v_n)\}$.

$\text{rank}(U_1)=1\implies \text{Im}(U_1)$ has dimension $1$, and its basis is singleton. So the basis is either $\{T((1,0))\}$ or $\{T((0,1))\}$; that is, it is spanned by any one of the first and second columns of $U_1$.

$\therefore\text{Im}(U_1)=\begin{cases}\text{span}\begin{bmatrix}2\cos^2(\theta/2)\\2\sin(\theta/2)\cos(\theta/2)\end{bmatrix},&\sin(\theta/2)=0\\\text{span}\begin{bmatrix}2\sin(\theta/2)\cos(\theta/2)\\2\sin^2(\theta/2)\end{bmatrix},&\cos(\theta/2)=0\end{cases}=\text{span}\begin{bmatrix}\cos(\theta/2)\\\sin(\theta/2)\end{bmatrix}$